# Which Linux Header file includes the definition of "struct iface"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In `/usr/include/net/if.h` on linux  struct iface is mentioned as a Back pointer to Interface in `ifaddr` structure, but i can't get the header file defining this structure.

Please help me if anyone knows !!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it's just a legacy code kept in the struct to keep its structure.

Comment: iface.h header is found in freeBSD only..not in linux?? Could you please tell me the path of iface.h in linux??

Answer (score 0):

`struct ifaddr` is of incomplete type, which means that the code would compile, but if you de-reference the pointer to `struct iface`, or make any other assignments, it would give an error. As said earlier, `struct iface` is kept in the main structure for legacy reasons only.

```
struct ifaddr
  {
    struct sockaddr ifa_addr;   /* Address of interface.  */
    union
      {
        struct sockaddr ifu_broadaddr;
        struct sockaddr ifu_dstaddr;
      } ifa_ifu;
    struct iface *ifa_ifp;      /* Back-pointer to interface.  */
        struct manav p[8];
    struct ifaddr *ifa_next;    /* Next address for interface.  */
  };
```

See also: [dereferencing pointer to incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700646/dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type)