# Error dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have two files, file.h and file.c

In the header file I have the following definitions:

```
struct openfile {
    struct vnode *of_vnode;
    struct lock *of_lock;
    off_t of_offset;
    int of_accmode; /* from open: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR */
    int of_refcount;
};
```

and

```
struct filetable {
    struct openfile *ft_openfiles[MAX_FILES];
};
```

I am trying to access the array of openfiles inside file.c. As an example,

```
int fd;
/* NULL-out the table */
for (fd = 0; fd < MAX_FILES; fd++) {
    curthread->t_filetable->ft_openfiles[fd] = NULL;
}
```

The line that access the ft_openfiles array is causing an error during compilation.

```
../../userprog/file.c:157: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

I have looked at a few related questions on here, but I don't really understand the mistake.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700646/dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type) is related.

Comment: What is `curthread` and what is `t_filetable`? Those are necessary

Comment: Also try replacing the problematic line with `curthread->t_filetable->ft_openfiles[fd] = {NULL};` and see if that works. If it does I'll put it in an answer.

Comment: These files are being used to manage opened files inside of the thread structure of a kernel. The initialization function may be called in several threads. curthread and t_filetable are needed to ensure I am only accessing the current thread's file system.

I replaced NULL with {NULL}, and I got the following error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

Answer (score 1):

The error mean that either curthread or t_filetable is of a type declared but not fully defined. One of them is a pointer of type void or the type definition is missing.

Following example will probably trigger the same error:

```
struct A;
struct A curthread;
```

Comment: What is this `class` you speak of. My `C` compiler never heard of it.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Good point, I did not realized the c (and not c++). Still, the answer is probably in the best range of hints given the question leak of information. Also, being ironic do not help here.

Comment: The reason I comment, instead of downvoting, is because it is indeed the correct answer. But the code example should pertain to the language being discussed. You won't post Javascript code here to demonstrate your point, would you? And there is no harm in injecting a bit of humor to ones commentary.

Comment: Absolutely correct.